# Swift - How can I override the SectionInset variable in a UICollectionViewLayout subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview

Currently I have this sub class and have assigned it to the UICollectionViewFlowLayout. When I override the itemSize variable, the cell changes accordingly. However, the insets do not get applied. I can change the top or any other value and it makes no difference.

However, if I add an inset with the storyboard it works fine.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
class RSSViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    private var size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.85, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5)
    private var edgeinset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 25, bottom: 15, right: 25)

    override var sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets{
        get{
            return self.edgeinset
        }
        set{
            self.edgeinset = newValue
        }
    }

    override var itemSize: CGSize{
        get{
            return self.size
        }
        set{
            self.size = newValue
        }
    }
}
```